# テキストとピッカーを用いた入力

Tags: swift, ios, iphone

テキストフィールドとピッカーを用いて、カレンダーの月と日を指定するものを作成したいです。現段階では、月を指定するものはできたのですが、もう一つ作る方法がわかりません。どうすればいいでしょうか？もう一つとは、もう一つテキストフィールドを作成して、そこに新しく日にちを選ぶピッカーを作成することです。つまり、テキストフィールド二つで別々にピッカーを作成したいです。

ソースコード

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return data[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        textField.text = data[row]
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    var pickerView = UIPickerView()
    var data = ["1", "2", "3","4", "5", "6","7", "8", "9","10", "11", "12"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createPickerView()
    }

    func createPickerView() {
        pickerView.delegate = self
        textField.inputView = pickerView
        // toolbar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 44)
        let doneButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.donePicker))
        toolbar.setItems([doneButtonItem], animated: true)
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }

    @objc func donePicker() {
        textField.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        textField.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: 日付を選択させたいと言うことであれば、普通は`UIDatePicker`を使うところだと思うのですが、特に使えない理由とかがあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

”月”用の`UIPickerView`と、”日”用の`UIPickerView`の二つのインスタンスを作る。そしてこれらをある方法で区別（識別）する。この方向で考えを進めていきます。
`UIPickerView`の`delegate`、`dataSource`には、一例を挙げると

```
optional func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
```

のように、第一引数に委譲元の`UIPickerView`のインスタンスをとります。この引数を使えば、`if`文で、二つの`UIPickerView`の識別を行うことができます。
そして、`UIPickerView`の識別は、親クラスである`UIView`のプロパティ`tag`を使ってできます。

[UIView - tag](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag)

この方針に基づくと、ご掲載のコードは、このように書き換えることができます。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!

    var pickerView1: UIPickerView!
    var pickerView2: UIPickerView!
    var data1: [String]!
    var data2: [String]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        data1 = [Int](1...12).map { String($0) }
        data2 = [Int](1...31).map { String($0) }
        pickerView1 = UIPickerView()
        pickerView2 = UIPickerView()
        createPickerViews()
    }

    func createPickerViews() {
        pickerView1.dataSource = self
        pickerView1.delegate = self
        pickerView1.tag = 1 // Caution!
        textField1.inputView = pickerView1
        
        pickerView2.dataSource = self
        pickerView2.delegate = self
        pickerView2.tag = 2 // Caution!
        textField2.inputView = pickerView2
        // toolbar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 44)
        let doneButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.donePicker))
        toolbar.setItems([doneButtonItem], animated: true)
        textField1.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        textField2.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }

    @objc func donePicker() {
        textField1.endEditing(true)
        textField2.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        textField1.endEditing(true)
        textField2.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    // Picker View's Delegates & DataSources
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return 12
        } else {
            return 31
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            return data1[row]
        } else {
            return data2[row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            textField1.text = data1[row]
        } else {
            textField2.text = data2[row]
        }
    }
}
```

コメント`// Caution!`の行で、`pickerView1`、`pickerView2`の`tag`を指定しています。

---

これで、「つまり、テキストフィールド二つで別々にピッカーを作成」することはできますが、問題の解決には至ってないことは、明らかだと思います。月の大小（31日まで、30日まで）、閏年の2月（28日まで、29日まで）など、対処しなければならない課題は残ったままです。もし私がプログラムを書くとしたら、コメント欄でOOPerさんがおっしゃるように、`UIDatePicker`を使うでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。回答だけでなく意図、予想できる課題まで解説していただいて勉強になりました。